# Reverse Bitwise operator

Tags: c#, vb.net, bit-manipulation

I've had a good search, spent a few hours of wasted time and I can't do a simple bit shift in reverse :(

```
Dim result = VALUE >> 8 And &HFF
```

I have existing code that reads VALUE (an UInt16) from a file, does the bit shift to it. What I am trying to do is the reverse of it so it can be saved and read using the existing code above.

I've read up in bit shifting and read this great [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V) article but it may as well be in Latin.

Comment: What is the question? How to get `VALUE` from the `result`? If so, why not `VALUE = result << 8`?

Comment: VALUE is saved in a file already bit-shifted. I want to be able to save the same. If I just go << 8 on a value then >> 8 &HFF you don't get the same value.

Comment: @Dmitry: That doesn't work for reconstructing `VALUE`. The code in OP gets the higher byte of a 16-bit word. You can't reconstruct 16 bits from 8, you need to also know the lower byte: `VALUE = higher << 8 | lower`. EDIT: It will work though if you don't need the lower byte (as it seems to be the case).

Comment: You cannot (fully) reverse this. Because some part of original `VALUE` is lost during operation

Comment: @ Orifjon Maybe he should try reading the UInt16 as a Uint32. Then he wouldn't lose a bit.

Comment: The dim result = statement does not change VALUE.  Also the And &HFF is superfluous.  It is not clear what you are asking.  Perhaps post more code that illustrates the problem better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UInt16 tt = 12123; //10111101011011
int aa = tt >> 8 & 0xFF; //101111 = 47
```

8 bits are disappeared. you can never get it back.

Comment: `VALUE >> 8` is literally the equivalent of saying "Divide by 2, eight times, forget about the remainder."

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value 54, in binary 110110

If you shift 54 >> 2, it moves the bit to the right

00110110
00011011 (shift once)
00001101 (shift twice)

You end up with 13. If you shift 13 to the left. 13 << 2

00001101
00011010 (shift once)
00110100 (shift twice)

You will end up with 52